# Angular 2 - Extract multiple variables from url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to extract multiple parameters from url. Suppose the url is like

`www.example.com/parent-component/2/list/child-component/5/list`

I want to extract the parameters `2` and `5`

The link on parent component is

```
[routerLink]="['/loggedIn','warehouse','move-request',moveRequest.id, 'issued-inventory',issuedInventory.id,'list']"
```

In the respective routes file i am doing this

```
{path:':move/issued-inventory',component:IssueInventoryComponent, children : ISSUED_INVENTORY_ROUTES}
```

The child route file is

```
{path:':myid/list',component:ListIssueInventoryComponent},
```

In the following component i want to access both variables `move` and `myid`

```
this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params : Params) =>
        {
           this.moveRequestId = params['move'];

        });
```

On Console the `moveRequestId` is undefined
What am i doing wrong? How to access those variables?

```
Router Version :     "@angular/router": "^3.3.1"
```

Comment: What does the ISSUED_INVENTORY_ROUTES look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first retrieve parent route to extract parent route parameter. But before doing that you need the `router` instance to get current route parent `ActivatedRoute`.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router){

}

this.sub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params : Params) => {
    //retrieve parent activated route
    const parentRoute = this.router.routerState.parent(activatedRoute);
    this.moveRequestId = params.params['move'];
});
```

---

Rather you could just refer to current activated route `snapshot` property, it already has reference to parent route.

```
let move = this.activatedRoute.parent.params['move'];
```